# How to set appropiate Nuget package to a C# Project in VS2010 Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I run a C# Project I get this error message:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567.

How can I set appropiate package to my project? I'm ssing VS 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to right click on the Solution node in Solution Explorer and select "Enable NuGet Package Restore". 
And after that right click on the Solution node in Solution Explorer and select "Restore NuGet Packages".

If "Restore NuGet Packages" did not appear or you do not have "Enable NuGet Package Restore", try to go to project options and select "NuGet Package Manager" -> General. Choose all points in "Package Restore" section.

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore).